# Visualisation of asymmetric placement of an object between two inclined mirrors

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics

Suppose two mirrors are inclined at an angle $x$ such that $n = 360/x$ is an odd integer.

If the object is at the angle sector then the number of images is $n-2$, I found the diagram for this case and could visualise it.

However, I was not able to visualise the case where the object is not on the angular bisector and the number of images = $n$.

Can someone please help me visualise this case?

I scavenged the web but couldn't find a single diagram for this case and am not able to make it on my own.

Comment: Try to construct a diagram similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR9DE.png) one.